# Error al insertar tabla en base de datos: "#1063 - Especificador de columna erróneo para la columna"

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando agregar una tabla a una base de datos, pero me arroja un error

> #1063 - Especificador de columna erróneo para la columna 'kcal'

```
CREATE TABLE `tabla`.`Alimentos` ( 
`id_alimento` INT(128) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`nombre` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`clasificacion` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`kcal` FLOAT(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '25.8' , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id_alimento`(120))
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Estuve revisando documentación u otros posts pero no me aparece demasiada información al respecto o cómo podría solucionar el error.

Comment: en el valor 255 de la longitud, pon por ejemplo (255,5)

Comment: Fue algo similar a lo que comentas: Tuve que eliminar la longitud al final de primary key, por lo que la consulta queda de ls siguiente forma :          
 CREATE TABLE `basedatos`.`Alimentos` ( 
`id_alimento` INT(128) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`nombre` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`clasificacion` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`kcal` FLOAT(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '25.8' , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id_alimento`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: Si lo solucionaste deberías de mostrar cómo, para que pueda ayudar a otros en un futuro

Comment: Revertí tu edición ya que el formato de [es.so] es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Pon _como respuesta_ tu solución, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, lee [ask] y [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Venia a comentar algo parecido, cuando definis la PRIMARY KEY no lleva el max de caracteres, eso se define en la columna.
Lo probé con el Workbench y me devolvió esto:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`alimentos` (
  `id_alimento` INT(128) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `clasificacion` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `kcal` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 25,8,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_alimento`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Incluso avisa que el INT(128) deberia ser solo INT